# How to handle an Empty IN clause inside a SQL Select Statement (IBatis 2)?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ibatis

I have written the following SQL Statment in IBatis version 2:

```
<select id="mySelect" resultClass="long" >
    SELECT  COUNT(*)        
    FROM    myTable 
    WHERE   myTable.columnA IN
        <iterate property="myInClauseValues" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">                    
                #myInClauseValues[]#                    
        </iterate>          
</select>
```

That statement works fine, if myInClauseValues (this is a ArrayList with Long) include at least one value. But if myInClauseValues is empty, I get an error message like this (I´m using an oracle database):

```
 Check the statement (query failed). 
 Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00936: Expression is missing
```

Comment: You can't have an empty `in`. check the size of your array and don't add it with it is empty

Comment: I agree with @juergen d. Check if the arraylist is empty, and only execute the query if it's not. Since the query will return no results if it's empty anyway, it's better not to go back and forth to the database for nothing.

If that for some crazy reason is not an option, you could try getting 'null' in between the parentheses of the IN clause when the arraylist is empty. That way the query will also just return zero results.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ibatis dyanmic query be a correct way??
eg:

```
<select id="mySelect" resultClass="long" >
    SELECT  COUNT(*)        
    FROM    myTable 
   <where>
    <isNotEmpty prepend="AND" property="myInClauseValues" >
       myTable.columnA IN
       <iterate property="myInClauseValues" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">                    
                    #myInClauseValues[]#                    
       </iterate>       
    </isNotEmpty>   
   </where>      
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry, but your solution doesn´t work! I get the same error message above: Check the statement (query failed). 
 Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00936: Expression is missing

Comment: answer edited.Please change isnotnull to isnotempty.

Comment: Sorry, but your solution doesn´t work again! I get the same error message !

Comment: Sorry,but as my experience isNotEmpty is should work.check my updated answer again and let me know any errors??

Comment: Could you please wirte a complete code example like this SELECT  COUNT(*)        
    FROM    myTable 
    WHERE   myTable.columnA IN <isNotEmpty prepend="AND" property="myInClauseValues" >
   myTable.columnA IN
   <iterate property="myInClauseValues" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">                    
                #myInClauseValues[]#                    
   </iterate>       
</isNotEmpty>

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to work with a group by clause inside this statement and how it must be implemented?

Comment: Not too difficut..Just set column which you want to make group.eg. select "your_group_by_column" , count(*) from ........ and them set group by under </iterate> tag. GROUP BY "your_group_by_column";