# How to handle SQL statements with an In clause and an empty Java List in IBatis2?

Tags: java, ibatis

I have created the following SQL Statement with IBatis2:

```
SELECT    COUNT(*)         
FROM    myTable
WHERE   myTable.id = 4711
AND     myTable.name = 'Maik'
AND     myTable.employee_id IN            
    <iterate property="employee_ids" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">                    
        #employee_ids[]#                    
    </iterate>
```

Now I have the problem, that employee_ids can be null or empty. In this case, the SQL statement will crash. How can I prevent a empty or nullable iteration in this SQL statement? "employee_ids" is a Java "List".

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It will be like that:

```
   SELECT    COUNT(*)         
   FROM    myTable
   WHERE   myTable.id = 4711
   AND     myTable.name = 'Maik'
   AND     myTable.employee_id IN     

   <if test="employee_ids!= null and employee_ids.size()>0">
     <iterate property="employee_ids" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">                    
    #employee_ids[]#                    
    </iterate>   
   </if> 
   <if test="employee_ids== null or employee_ids.size()==0">  
    <![CDATA[
    ()
    ]]
    >
   </if>
```

Comment: I use IBatis2 and there is no If tag !

Comment: I haven't noticed that it is 2 version. Perhaps. this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359831/how-to-handle-an-empty-in-clause-inside-a-sql-select-statement-ibatis-2

Answer (score 1):

For `IBatis 2`, you can use dynamic sql `isNotEmpty` to check null or empty list.

For your case, try as follows.

```
SELECT    COUNT(*)         
FROM    myTable
WHERE   myTable.id = 4711
AND     myTable.name = 'Maik'
<dynamic>
<isNotEmpty prepend="AND" property="employee_ids">
    myTable.employee_id IN            
    <iterate property="employee_ids" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">                    
        #employee_ids[]#                    
    </iterate>
</isNotEmpty>
</dynamic>
```